# Sherlock Action Bar Styling (DropDown Spinner Navigation)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, styling

I am trying to change the drop down background of the sherlock action bar as well as its text color. Here's what I have tried:

```
<style name="DropDown" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#EDEDED</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#A9A9A9</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItemStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/devcheckStyle">
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDown</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDown</item>
   <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>
</style>
```

The main theme being `MyTheme`, with the following code I am getting the desirable background color, but I am getting nowhere with the text's color inside the drop down navigation. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Put that code

```
 <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
```

into your MyTheme code should be like:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/devcheckStyle">
 <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDown</item>
 <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDown</item>
 <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>
 <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>
</style>
```